# sudo nautilus looks different from nautilus

Tags: nautilus, themes, 16.10, gtk3

[image: Picture]

I want Nautilus to look like this by default, but it is only looks like this when called with `sudo nautilus`

How can I fix this theme problem?

(Note: same problem on terminal or any other application too)

(Gtk:3.22, Ubuntu 16.10, Open Source AMD Drivers)

Comment: Please do yourself a favor : never run sudo nautilus - it might break things ... in case you urgently need to run nautilus as root (as I said : not recommended !), install gksu and run : gksudo dbus-launch nautilus ! :)

Comment: But sudo nautilus better than normal I see :) all the problems from non-root things. Do you know why is this happening? Themes are not stable :(

Comment: Maybe something went wrong during the installation process ... did you perform a clean installation of Ubuntu 16.10 or did you upgrade the operating system from Ubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu 16.10 ? :)

Comment: It was a clean installation from 16.10 iso. Do you know anything so I can fix this? Maybe re-installing some apps? Or anything. I'm not a pro user of linux :)

Comment: I booted from USB and ran nautilus from live Ubuntu 16.10, it was same. Maybe this is a problem about ubuntu or unity itself?

Comment: Unity ? Those screenshots you provided look completely different from the nautilus design of Unity ... which desktop environment are you using ? Or do you use a 3rd party theme instead of ambiance or radiance ? This could be an explanation, because 3rd party themes sometimes are breaking things ... :)

Comment: Yeah I'm using another Flat theme. (w/ Gnome Tweak Tool).

But I think it must looks nice, for example I'm using solus os now, and the same theme at solus works perfectly. I love Unity desktop but I want to customize it, but when I attempt to change it from defaults, "broken!" :) At other desktop environments I have never seen a bug like this.